# "Bad request" when trying to upload file

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, error, file

I am trying to upload file via C# to sharepoint server 2013, I copy pasted the code [from here](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/41872624b010f3f5c730).

I just added inside the constructor my credentials, like:

```
public SharePointClient(string webUri)
{
   Credentials=new NetworkCredential("myusername","mypassword");
}
```

And I'm calling the upload function from the main class:

```
var url="http://codey-sharepoint/sites/codey";
var sharepoint=new SharePointClient(url);
sharepoint.UploadFileAsChuncks(url,"D:\\test.txt");
```

But, I'm getting "BadRequest" exception at:

```
...
if (firstChunk)
{
   endpointUrl = string.Format("{0}/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/startupload(uploadId=guid'{2}')", BaseAddress, uriAddress.LocalPath, uploadId);
    this.UploadData(endpointUrl, buffer);   //<----- here exception
    firstChunk = false;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to debug endpointUrl. What is the value?

Comment: @Raf It looks like: `http://codey-sharepoint/sites/codey/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/sites/codey')/startupload(uploadId=guid'933907ff-f426-42bc-aff4-a4cb8f79114a')`

Comment: @Codey, since `getfilebyserverrelativeurl` expects **file** server relative path, try to specify `getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/sites/codey/path/filename')` instead of  `getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/sites/codey')`

Comment: @VadimGremyachev Thanks for replay, please see my replay to Lee_MSFT's answer

Answer (score 1):

Sample test code in my local SharePoint 2016.

Pay attention to `add a empty file first, hardcode the library for testing purpose, update it accordingly`

```
public void UploadFileAsChunks(string address, string fileName, int chunkSize = 2048)
        {
            var uriAddress = new Uri(address);
            var fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
            SetupRequest(HttpMethod.Post);

            var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

            //add a empty file first, hardcode the library for testing purpose, update it accordingly
            var emptyEndpointUrl = string.Format("{0}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/mydoc')/Files/add(url='{2}',overwrite=true)", BaseAddress, uriAddress.LocalPath, fi.Name);
            this.UploadData(emptyEndpointUrl, new byte[] { });

            if (fi.Length <= chunkSize)
            {
                //this.UploadFile(address, fi.Name);                
                var UpdateEmptyEndpointUrl = string.Format("{0}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/mydoc')/Files/add(url='{2}',overwrite=true)", BaseAddress, uriAddress.LocalPath, fi.Name);
                this.UploadData(emptyEndpointUrl, fileContent);
                return;
            }                                             

            var endpointUrl = string.Format("{0}/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/savebinarystream", BaseAddress, uriAddress.LocalPath);

            var firstChunk = true;
            var uploadId = Guid.NewGuid();
            var offset = 0L;
            using (var inputStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileName))
            {
                var buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    if (firstChunk)
                    {
                        endpointUrl = string.Format("{0}/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/startupload(uploadId=guid'{2}')", BaseAddress, uriAddress.LocalPath, uploadId);
                        this.UploadData(endpointUrl, buffer);
                        firstChunk = false;
                    }
                    else if (inputStream.Position == inputStream.Length)
                    {
                        endpointUrl = string.Format("{0}/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/finishupload(uploadId=guid'{2}',fileOffset={3})", BaseAddress, uriAddress.LocalPath, uploadId, offset);
                        var finalBuffer = new byte[bytesRead];
                        Array.Copy(buffer, finalBuffer, finalBuffer.Length);
                        this.UploadData(endpointUrl, finalBuffer);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        endpointUrl = string.Format("{0}/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/continueupload(uploadId=guid'{2}',fileOffset={3})", BaseAddress, uriAddress.LocalPath, uploadId, offset);
                        this.UploadData(endpointUrl, buffer);
                    }
                    offset += bytesRead;
                }
            }
        }
```

Call the lib.

```
var url = "http://sp:12001";
            var sharepoint = new SharePointClient(url);
            sharepoint.UploadFileAsChunks("http://sp:12001/Mydoc/screen.gif", "C:\\Lee\\screen.gif");
            Console.WriteLine("complete");
```

Comment: It creates an empty file, but when It goes into "first chunck" uploaddata mehod with this url `http://codey-sharepoint/sites/codey/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/codey/Shared Documents/300MB.txt')/startupload(uploadId=guid'26903998-f2ce-4f83-91f1-0e3541517a8c')` I'm getting `404 Not Found`

Comment: Does 300MB.txt created? if created, should not raise 404 based on my testing.

Comment: I suspect that `getfilebyserverrelativeurl` doesn't work for sharepoint 2013 @Lee_MSFT

Comment: Missing the tag, SharePoint 2013, suppose you're using 2016, startupload is available from SharePoint 2016.

Comment: so there is no way to upload large files (~1GB) to sharepoit server 2013 ? I have tried with [SaveBinaryDirect](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/upload-large-files-sample-app-for-sharepoint#before-you-begin) and all other options in the link, but nothing worked for files>300 MB. evan taht I succeded to upload manually

Comment: can you provide the link again?

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepointdevelopersupport/2016/11/23/always-use-file-chunking-to-upload-files-250-mb-to-sharepoint-online/

Comment: Check below threads, should be helpful.  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenh/2012/11/15/issues-uploading-large-files-to-sharepoint/    https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.LargeFileUpload